# Internal Texture Format

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

On Android using OpenGL ES 2.0 I try to perform certain performance tests using different internal texture formats. 
Initially I have a lot of RGBA textures (png) which I want to load and store internally in a different format with OpenGL (for example RGB and LUMINANCE). I load my textures using glTexImage2D like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),resourceId);
...
int size = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(b);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, bitmap.getWidth(),    
                    bitmap.getHeight(), 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, 
                    GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, b);
```

This works fine, however if I change the first GLES20.GL_RGBA (The internalFormat parameter) to anything else (GLES20.GL_RGB or GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE) my texture appears all black. Changing the second GLES20.GL_RGBA to the same value will display something - but obviously not correctly as the original data is RGBA.

I thought maybe it has something to with the shader code - that maybe texture2D(..) returns a different value because the internal format of the texture is different. My shader code is simply:

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, fragment_texture_coordinate);
```

I tried changing this around too, but no luck yet. So I thought maybe glTex2DImage is not at all working as I think it does (I am not an expert on this area whatsoever).

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
I overlooked this little detail on texImage2D. It appears that:

*internalformat must match format. No conversion between formats is supported during texture image processing. type may be used as a hint to specify how much precision is desired, but a GL implementation may choose to store the texture array at any internal resolution it chooses.*

What I gather from this, is that if you want to store your textures different from their original format you'll have to convert it yourself.

Comment: i tried to find the solution for few weeks ... no f..ing chance ... BitmapFactory.decodeXXXXX is premultiplying alpa https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/uqbDPmP4L8o ... the only way is to build own loader ... i'm using jni with libpng now

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't think pre-multiplied alpha is the problem here. My images do not have any (semi) transparent pixels.

Comment: from http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml : `format
Specifies the format of the texel data. Must match internalformat. The following symbolic values are accepted: GL_ALPHA, GL_RGB, GL_RGBA, GL_LUMINANCE, and GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA.` are the RGB and LUMINANCE connected if so why don't you use use A chanel as LUMINANCE?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link. Strange I overlooked this : `internalformat must match format. No conversion between formats is supported during texture image processing. type may be used as a hint to specify how much precision is desired, but a GL implementation may choose to store the texture array at any internal resolution it chooses.`
So basicly it is only possible to store it so if my texture is already in a RGB/Luminance format (Or converted before the GL call).

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment shader must be written to agree with the format you are giving to glTexImage2D().  For GL_RGB, it should force the alpha to 1.0, like this:

```
vec3 Color_RGB = texture2D(sampler2d, texCoordinate);
gl_FragColor = vec4(Color_RGB, 1.0);
```

But, for GL_RGBA, it should look like this:

```
vec4 Color_RGBA = texture2D(sampler2d, texCoordinate);
gl_FragColor = Color_RGBA;
```

And, as has been discussed, you can only use the Android Bitmap class for textures if your PNG files have no transparency.  This article explains that:
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think this is true. `vec3 Color_RGB = texture2D(sampler2d, texCoordinate);` does not compile because texture2D(...) returns a vec4 always. Changing vec3 to vec4 does compile but results in a completely black texture so it's probably not loaded at all. Not that strange if you read my Edit. 
On the other hand, manually converting the Bitmap pixel data to RGB and then loading it as RGB works like a charm without adjusting anything in the shader code.
The problem with premultiplied alpha is of no concern to me at this point. The provided link is helpful though :).

Comment: Yes, texture2D() does always return a vec4, my mistake.  But changing vec3 to vec4 will make the alpha part always 0.0 by default, which will give you a black display, unless you set it to 1.0.  I'm not sure what you mean by manually converting the Bitmap, but any conversion should be done in the fragment shader because it's much faster than Java.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also set alpha to 1.0, otherwise I will get a transparant texture. With manually converting I mean reading the pixel (RGBA) data from the Bitmap class, and writing for example only RGB values to a buffer - and use that buffer for texImage2D with internalFormat and format parameters set to RGB in this case. This works with using just `gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, texcoordinate);`. Now the texture is internally stored as RGB. I need this conversion to happen at load time, not in the fragment shader as texture2D(..) appears to be faster on say LUMINANCE than RGBA.